# How to return '@GetMapping' model attributes to BootStrap modal?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

**Goal**: pass set of enumerated values to Thymeleaf as checkboxes in a each loop. **Problem:** The Bootstrap modal is part of the event calendar implemented/accessed in JS. When the user clicks the day, the modal opens up, but the *return* statement from *@GetMapping* doesn't pass the model attributes to the modal. **TESTED:** without the Bootstrap modal (that is, direct on HTML file) the each loop worked, but in the modal it doesn't. **Assumption:** The modal is one level above the HTML file when it's open. I suppose it's only accessible through JS/Ajax. 
Anyone who could help please?

**Controller**

```
(...)

@GetMapping("/getEvent")
public String getEvent(Model theModel) {
    theModel.addAttribute("event", new Event());  
    theModel.addAttribute("serviceLayers", EnumServiceLayers.values()); 
    return "views/kalender";
}

@PostMapping("/saveEvent")
public String saveEvent(@RequestParam(value = "date") String date){
    eventService.saveEvent(date);
    return "redirect:/eventController/showCalendar";
}
```

**HTML** - *Note: the Event class has a list field for the enum class *EnumServiceLayers*, so no *th:object="${enumServiceLayers}"* required, only the model attribute.

```
<div class="myForm">
    <form th:action="@{/eventController/saveEvent}" th:object="${event}" method="POST">

    (...)

    <!--Model attribute 'serviceLayers' is used only within <ul> in the whole form -->
    <ul>
        <li th:each="service : ${serviceLayers}">
            <label th:text="${service}"></label>
            <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{enumServiceLayers}" th:value="${service}">       
        </li>
    </ul>

    (...)
```

**JS/Ajax**

*i.* This statement adds to each day an event listener - which is working properly: no problem here. Just as insight.

```
(...)

day_element.addEventListener('click', function() {addDayEvt(year, month, day);});

(...)
```

*ii.* The modal is handled in JS - and where maybe the model attribute could be passed in, so it's captured in/by the modal?

```
//DAY CELL EVENT LISTENER
function addDayEvt(ayear, amonth, aday){

   // Uncheck check-boxes
   showUnchecked(); 
   selectedDate = formatDate(ayear, amonth, aday);

   //alert(selectedDate);
   if (!(aday < today.getDate()) && !((amonth+1) < (today.getMonth()+1)) || (ayear > today.getFullYear())) {

      //Call @GetMapping in Spring controller?          
      $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: '/eventController/getEvent',
         dataType: 'json'
      });

      $('.myForm #date').val(selectedDate); //date field
      $('.myForm #exampleModal').modal(); //opens modal
   }
} //END DAY CELL EVENT LISTENER
```

Thank you very much in advance

Murilo

Comment: REST note: Your resource is named `event`. Don't specify "controller", and you already said `GET` in the verb. `GET /events/{id}`, and `POST /events`.

Comment: I didn't quite understand where you mean by 'GET /events/{id}'. Do you mean I don't need to use '/eventController', only '/getEvent' in the url? If not, could you please give an example?

Comment: _Also_ do not use `getEvent`. That's what the HTTP `GET` is for. Use `@GetMapping("/events/{id}")`.